# Value difference in computed columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following query, computed columns [Total Amount] and [Received Amount] are getting calculated from [PO Quantity] and [Recieved_Qty] respectively. Also, if we see in the output records(attached), although  [PO Quantity] and [Recieved_Qty] have exactly same values, still there is difference in [Total Amount] and [Received Amount].

```
select 
    [vendor]
    ,round(cast([PO Quantity] as float),2)[PO Quantity]
    ,round([Recieved_Qty],2)[Recieved_Qty]
    ,[Net Price],round(([PO Quantity]*[Net Price]),2)[Total Amount]
    ,round(([Recieved_Qty]*[Net Price]),2)[Received Amount]
    ,round((([PO Quantity]*[Net Price])-(Recieved_Qty*[Net Price])),2)[Balance Amount]
from [dbo].[Base_file8]
and [PO Quantity]>[Recieved_Qty] 
and [country] not in ('IN')
```

Please help in finding the solution.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Output records:

    vendor  PO Quantity Recieved_Qty    Net Price   Total Amount    Received Amount Balance Amount
    10025407    452.62  452.62          2105.17     952846.28       952842.04       4.24
    10025407    295.35  295.35          2105.17     621766.15       621761.97       4.18
    10025407    503.2   503.2           2105.17     1059325.75     1059321.57       4.18
    10025407    403.9   403.9           1895.83     765729.54       765725.73       3.82
    10025407    251.66  251.66          1979.01     498043.58       498037.66       5.92
```

Comment: I don't see a question, what is it you need help with? EDIT: Is it something with decimal differences in calculations between TOTAL and RECIEVED?

Comment: PO quantity data type float.... imprecision may cause math errors.  decimal (16,4) 12 numbers to left 4 to right of decimal may be a better choice.

Comment: Sure that query works without a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: What are the data types for PO quantity and Received QTY  what's the formula for the computed columns? (Show DDL of base_file8 table)  also rounding.  ***add a PO Quantity w/o any rounding and received_QTY w/o rounding if the values are different you have your answer.*** since you do no rounding in the total and received amount calculations.  My guess is the ACTUAL values of those fields VARY from the displayed values of those fields.

Comment: PO Quantity has data type(real) with max length as 4.Received_Qty has data type(real) with max length as 4 and Net Price has data type(float) with max length as 8. Also, unrounding PO Quanitity and Received Quantity initially and rounding them in Total Amount did not make any difference.

Comment: I am new to SQL. Please help me with the queries.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2014.

Comment: FYI: REAL and FLOAT are both floating points: Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly. So i"m back to show me the full value of PO Quantity and received_Quantity without rounding.  I'm betting the value stored in the database is different and as such results in different amounts.  My answer below goes into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that PO quantity and Received_QTY have more decimal values than the 2 digits you're rounding to and that those values are different.  As a result when you multiply those numbers by different decimal values you end up with different pennies based on when rounding is occurring.  You need to determine if you want to round the quantity first or round the quantity after the multiplication by price.  My guess is AFTER thus you shouldn't round the values being displayed for PO quantity nor received qty.

add unrounded values and compare the difference in values.

or round before the * net price then round again after; though this is bad form, you should only round once when you go to display the data or store the rounded value when you show your end user the cost/price.

also bad spelling on column received qty... I before E except after C... :P

```
 SELECT [vendor]
     , [PO Quantity] [PO Quantity Unrounded]
     , [Recieved_Qty] [Recieved_Qty unrounded]
     , round([PO Quantity],2) [PO Quantity]
     , round([Recieved_Qty],2) [Recieved_Qty]
     , [Net Price]
     , round((round([PO Quantity],2)*[Net Price]),2) [Total Amount] 
     , round((round([Recieved_Qty],2)*[Net Price]),2) [Received Amount] 
     , round((([PO Quantity]*[Net Price])-(Recieved_Qty*[Net Price])),2) [Balance Amount]
FROM [dbo].[Base_file8]
 and [PO Quantity]>[Recieved_Qty] 
 and [country] not in ('IN')
```

I'd probably do it this way:

```
 SELECT [vendor]
     , [PO Quantity] [PO Quantity]
     , [Recieved_Qty] [Recieved_Qty]
     , [Net Price]
     , round([PO Quantity]*[Net Price]),2) [Total Amount] 
     , round([Recieved_Qty]*[Net Price]),2) [Received Amount] 
     , round(([PO Quantity]*[Net Price])-(Recieved_Qty*[Net Price]),2) [Balance Amount]
FROM [dbo].[Base_file8]
 and [PO Quantity]>[Recieved_Qty] 
 and [country] not in ('IN')
```

This way the rounding is done once after the math thus we don't lose $ due to rounding early and the final amount is only rounded once. so at most we lose or gain 1 cent.

There's a reason the creators of the system stored x decimal values on a qty.  you should use them all when doing the math.